# ViewState in web part becomes null after some idle time

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-web-part, viewstate

I am storing some values in ViewState in my WebPart user control in SP2013. After some idle time, say 40 minutes when I try to access those values from ViewState i always get null result. Is it due to session expires and it also make ViewState blank causing this behavior. Can someone please guide me on this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that web application has a setting that can be controlled through Powershell

```
$web = Get-SPWebApplication "http://mywebapp..." $web.FormDigestSettings.TimeOut
```

This is by default **30 minutes** and SharePoint **Viewstate** cache is **cleared** after `FormDigestSettings.TimeOut +1 (i.e. 31 minutes)`

```
$web.FormDigestSettings.TimeOut = New-TimeSpan -Hours 1 -Minutes 0
```

Increasing this time out might have some performance implications.

Kindly check below article.

[AppFabric Caching (and SharePoint): Configuration and Deployment (Part 2)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/besidethepoint/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-configuration-and-deployment-part-2/)

Comment: Did you get it working?

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I need to change. Thanks again. You saved my day :)